# Xamarin based apps not showing in the emulator for iOS, Droid and Windows phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mobile, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am using the latest build of VS 2015 with update 2 which has the Xamarin Framework installed as well. I am following this example [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/) 
I noticed that my code with the current framework that I have installed doesn't support this line `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();` shown in the windows phone section in part 2 [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/deepdive/) of the documentation. Neither does it support the `PhoneCallTask` class on point #27 in [part 1](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/)

I am having a problem figuring out what `Init` takes as a parameter in `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();`. Where can I find an example of what I should pass in of type `IActivatedEventArgs`?

Its not just the app in the Windows emulator that doesn't show anything on the emulator screen like in the screenshots. The app doesn't show any UI on the Droid or iOS emulators too.

I landed on these pages from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt299001.aspx), so I assumed the examples showed to be fit for the latest release of VS2015. The documentation seems outdated for the latest framework here, or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: I know this is late, but does that Phoneword sample work if you just download it from https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Phoneword? If so, then it would seem you made some error making your own version when following the quick start guide. 

Also it is only on Android that anything needs to be passed to `Forms.Init(this, bundle);` where "this" is the activity and "bundle" is the bundle passed into OnCreate.